# Good way to handle multiple clipboard in emacs

Tags: emacs, emacs24

I am using the Mac OS command line version Emacs 24.3. And the copy and post in Emacs could be a little messy as the *C-k*, *C-d* and other command could replace the content in the clipboard as we use *C-y*.

I am wondering whether there is a multiple clipboard system like *yn* and *pn* in Vim.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is a such system called "Registers": http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Registers.html

Answer (score 0):

There is also a secondary selection. See the Emacs manual, node `Secondary Selection`.
See also [Secondary Selection](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SecondarySelection) and library [`second-sel.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/second-sel.el), which facilitates using the secondary selection.